# what is newID() in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, newid

what is newID() in sql server ?

Comment: Have a look at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: Refer this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276822%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: what happened, is your search broken?

Answer (score 0):

> Creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

see this link for more info [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)